# Django REST Framework show multiple forms on HTML view

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, custom-routes

I have a ViewSet using Django REST Framework that has both standard and custom routes. The serializer for each route is different.

Example:

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):

    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @decorators.detail_route(methods=['put'])
    def change_password(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserChangePasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        ...

    @decorators.detail_route(methods=['put'])
    def update_prefs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer(data=request.data)
        ...
```

I have everything working such that I can perform standard get, post, put, delete actions on the User object and the two extra routes work. However, I can't figure out how to make the HTML forms for the custom routes display when using the `BrowsableAPIRenderer`. It would be very handy for developers to be able to see forms demonstrating the fields that are expected on the above put methods, for example.

I tried adding get methods for the two routes, but this is non-sensical for the first one. Regardless, I don't see the right serializer displayed when I go to the URL for the route, I see the serializer specified in `serializer_class`.

About the only thing I haven't tried is overriding `get_serializer_class()` because this involves putting knowledge of every serializer for every route in a single place rather than being able to specify the serializer within the route method itself... is this the way I should be trying to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to *not* use `serializer_class` and instead override `get_serializer_class`. Since this takes an action, I can `if..elif..else` on that to return the right serializer. Clever use of a dictionary then makes this easy:

```
serializers = {
    'DEFAULT': UserSerializer,
    'password_update': PasswordUpdateSerializer,
    'register': UserRegisterSerializer,
}

def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.serializers.get(self.action, self.serializers['DEFAULT'])
```

This will return the `UserSerializer` for all actions unless I specify a different serializer in the `serializers` dictionary. Easier than I thought it would be.